# How to dispatch Mouse event with fixed X and Y Typescript

Tags: typescript, mouseevent, dispatchevent

I am trying to dispatch a mouse Event with fixed X and Y variables to test some things. It is the only way to do it. I want to dispatch a mouse Event where I can set the X and Y in programm code upon calling the window.dispatchEvent function.

Something like this would be great:

`var ev: Event = new Event(100,200); window.dispatchEvent(ev);`

I have tried a lot of things but I couldn't find any way to solve this issue.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) of the type you like with the `clientX` and `clientY` properties configured as follows:

```js
const event = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
  clientX: 100,
  clientY: 200
});

window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY));

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```